# MVC3 Client Side Validation Firing Unexpectedly (Without Validation Attributes Applied)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I just ran into a situation that had me pulling my hair out for a good while and I'm at a loss to explain why. In the end, the only thing I could do was turn off client-side validation.

We've had MVC3 code in a production environment for over a year that has used a combination of client-side and server-side validation. The bulk of the validation is done server-side, but we've had the client-side validation turned on for [Required] fields so a trip to the server doesn't have to be made if one of those is missing, since client-side stuff gets checked first.

This morning, all of a sudden, we're getting client-side validation errors for fields that **DO NOT** have [Required] attributes on them! Why is this happening?

The field that was throwing the client-side error only has server-side validation, because it's part of a complex set of properties that have to be checked together. I put a breakpoint on that validation line in code and it never reached it because it was getting validated on the client-side as a required field despite not having that attribute at all (the property has no validation attributes on it at all).

I don't understand this. I looked at the source for the web page on the client and there it is: the javascript for client-side validation. But nowhere in the code for the model do we have specified that that property should be required or any other validation attribute.

What gives? I thought client-side validation code was only generated for properties that have attributes specified?

Comment: Do you happen to have `class="required"` on those field? jQuery Validate will automatically fire if that attribute is present...

Comment: are you strongly typing the views with the domain models?

Comment: I am not specifying any required attributes or classes. I am, however, using Html.DropDownListFor(), and apparently it creates all this client-side validation whether I specify it or not. That's rather disappointing.

Comment: @ChrisHolmes then probably the fields that are set to not null in the db are causing the validation to fire, when you drag drop the tables on the designer, domain classes generate by entity framework make them required...

Comment: We don't drag-drop design. Ever. There are no [Required] fields anywhere on the model or viewModel for those properties.